# Spring boot jpa H2 compatibility mode MYSQL not working

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, h2

I am using `Date` function in my query so I am trying to run `H2` in `MYSQL` mode for my `SpringBoot JPA` application. I have added `url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=MYSQL` in my `application.yml` file because I got the error `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "DATE" not found; SQL statement`.

But even after adding that `mode=mysql` property in `aplicaiton.ymll` file I am still getting same error. Is there anything else I need to add in any where?

Here is my Application.yml

```
spring: 
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;Mode=MYSQL
```

My Query

```
@Query(value = "select * from user where  Date(created_date) <= ?1 and Date(modified_date) <= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Users> usersByDate(String date );
```

I am creating the table schema by spring/hibernate  with the javax.persistence annotations in my entity. I am using `spring-boot 1.4.2` and `spring-data-jpa 1.10.5` . Unable to understand why it is not working for me.

Comment: Personally I would always test using the actual DBMS, we always run test inside a Docker image, giving us a clean DB for every test run.

Comment: The fact that you are using mode=MYSQL doesn't mean it support 100% all the features and functions of mysql... See the H2 documentation what the compatibility mode does.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make this work (although it feels more like a hack). They do have an implementation, but they've provided it as a pluggable module for some reason. The class in question is this: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/blob/master/h2/src/main/org/h2/mode/FunctionsMySQL.java

To top off the list of problems, this class isn't packaged in the maven jar currently available.

So I copied it in my source. For non-spring uses, this needs to be called:
    `FunctionsMYSQL.register(connection);`

For spring-jdbc based uses, since we won't have direct access to `java.sql.Connection`, (in my case spring boot jdbc starter), this sql needs to be executed before using the function:
    `CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS DATE FOR "org.h2.mode.FunctionsMySQL.date";`

This class also has implementations for UNIX_TIMESTAMP and FROM_UNIXTIME. I used UNIX_TIMESTAMP by plugging it into schema.sql (which spring-jdbc automatically executes in the beginning).

Comment: This has just been added.  I have been using 1.4.197 and the class didn't exist.  I've just updated to 1.4.199 and that class now exists.